# Organizing Sales Data Using Excel Macros

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I am writing a macro function in Excel to organize a set of monthly sales data.  The original format uses 6 rows per entry, and the organized table uses only 1.  The number of sales changes every month, so I need to figure out a way to identify how many sales entries there are so that I know how far to extend my formulas.

At the end of the raw data always appears the word "SIGNED:" in the second column, so I used the indirect and match functions to determine how far to filldown the formulas.  The code that I used looks like this:

```
    Application.Goto Reference:= _
         "INDIRECT(""T"" & (MATCH(""SIGNED:"",RawData!C2:C2,0)-3)/6+1)"
    Range("T2", Selection).Select
    Selection.FillDown
```

And it worked great initially, except that apparently sometimes the raw data doesn't use 6 rows because sometimes the match function with the above inputs does not return a whole number.  So I tried using a ceiling function around the match function to insure that I get a whole number, and figured it would be okay if it is off by one or two as that is easily dealt with manually.  What I wrote looks like this:

```
    Application.Goto Reference:= _
        "INDIRECT(""T"" & Ceiling((MATCH(""SIGNED:"",RawData!C[-20],0)-3)/6+1),1))"
    Range("A2", Selection).Select
    Selection.FillDown
```

Now I get an error and I can't figure out why.  Does it have to do with the format of the number returned by the ceiling function?  I would greatly appreciate any help in coming to a solution, or perhaps even a different approach to finding the number of sales entries.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this somewhat differently. The code fragment below uses the .Find property of ranges to determine the last cell of data in the worksheet. .Find returns a cell reference, and we can get its row by using the .Row property.

Note also that it isn't necessary to select ranges to act on them.

```
Dim lastcell As Range
Set lastcell = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
Range("A2:A" & lastcell.Row).FillDown
```